# Apc working fine after file upload completes.Not working during file upload in progress

Tags: apc

Below details are my apc config

```
apc.cache_by_default    On  On
apc.canonicalize    On  On
apc.coredump_unmap  Off Off
apc.enable_cli  Off Off
apc.enabled On  On
apc.file_md5    Off Off
apc.file_update_protection  2   2
apc.filters no value    no value
apc.gc_ttl  3600    3600
apc.include_once_override   Off Off
apc.lazy_classes    Off Off
apc.lazy_functions  Off Off
apc.max_file_size   8M  8M
apc.mmap_file_mask  no value    no value
apc.num_files_hint  1000    1000
apc.preload_path    no value    no value
apc.report_autofilter   Off Off
apc.rfc1867 On  On
apc.rfc1867_freq    0   0
apc.rfc1867_name    APC_UPLOAD_PROGRESS APC_UPLOAD_PROGRESS
apc.rfc1867_prefix  upload_ upload_
apc.rfc1867_ttl 3600    3600
apc.serializer  default default
apc.shm_segments    1   1
apc.shm_size    128 128
apc.shm_strings_buffer  4M  4M
apc.slam_defense    On  On
apc.stat    On  On
apc.stat_ctime  Off Off
apc.ttl 0   0
apc.use_request_time    On  On
apc.user_entries_hint   4096    4096
apc.user_ttl    0   0
apc.write_lock  On  On
```

Comment: Please share your ideas to find out the reason why its not working

Comment: Can you expand on "not working"?

Comment: which webserver do you use? did you name html form fields as the following?: `apc.rfc1867_name APC_UPLOAD_PROGRESS APC_UPLOAD_PROGRESS
apc.rfc1867_prefix upload_ upload_`

Comment: This is the link am testing http://67.228.0.83/chaddemo/test_apc.php

Comment: during upload process am getting below error  <br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Division by zero in <b>/home/drupalcu/public_html/chaddemo/getprogress.php</b> on line <b>10</b><br />
0 test_apc.php:35
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Division by zero in <b>/home/drupalcu/public_html/chaddemo/getprogress.php</b> on line <b>10</b><br />
0 ...After complete am getting value Array ( [total] => 169195 [current] => 169195 [rate] => 252646.416071 [filename] => 415958_2904415229697_1952659607_o (1).jpg [name] => test_file [cancel_upload] => 0 [done] => 1 [start_time] => 1375518131.94 )

Comment: please see error in console browser